# W/PathParser: Points are too far apart Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

hello when I'm trying to move  Navigation Drawer  to one of the fragments its jumps to the main activity XML and not to the fragment,I've try to check if my import class are the same i used android library and support library and it didn't helped.

this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();



    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new FirstFragment());
    }


    else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new SecondFragment());


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new ThirdFragment() );
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting the next message when I'm trying to press on one of the items:
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
Any suggestion?

Comment: To me it shows that error if I keep the icons of the template, once changed disappears

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found my problem i was missing a command,
Need to replace this code:

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new FirstFragment());
}
```

with this code:

```
if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new FirstFragment()).commit();
    }
```

I was missing the .commit command.

Comment: Well, good that you solved the issue but `W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461` isn't related to fragment transaction. It is warning related to svg/vectors.

Comment: Such a coincident many of us met the same problem **and** saw the same unrelated warning the `W/PathParser:` thing.

Comment: I don't find any solution regarding this, is it safe to just fold the lines like this in log cat or we need to find any solution to it ??

Comment: @AalapPatel Hi there please read Omkar Comment, I can say that my app runs perfectly although these warnings coming up

Comment: Old question I know but for posterity's sake.... I got this error when an id was wrong in mobile_navigation.xml for one of the fragments accessed from the nav drawer. I wonder if in doing the above you corrected this file without realising.

Comment: @Matt I don't really remember but I think it didn't fix this error, you should check though